# Imperative vs Functional Programming in Ruby

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, immutability, performance

I am reading this article about how to program in Ruby in Functional Style.
https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming

One of the examples that took my attention is the following:

```
# No (mutable):
output = []
output << 1
output << 2 if i_have_to_add_two
output << 3

# Yes (immutable):
output = [1, (2 if i_have_to_add_two), 3].compact
```

Whereas the "mutable" option is less safe because we changing the value of the array,  the inmutable one seems less efficient because it calls `.compact`. That means  that it has to iterate the array to return a new one without the nil's values.

In that case, which option is preferible? And in general how do you choose between immutability (functional) vs performance (in the case when the imperative solution is faster)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not wrong. It is often the case that a purely functional solution will be slower than a destructive one. Immutable values generally mean a lot more allocation has to go on unless the language is very well optimized for them (which Ruby isn't).

However, it doesn't often matter. Worrying about the performance of specific operations is not a great use of your time 99% of the time. Shaving off a microsecond from a piece of code that runs 100 times a second is simply not a win.

The best approach is usually to do whatever makes your code cleanest. Very often this means taking advantage of the functional features of the language — for example, `map` and `select` instead of `map!` and `keep_if`. Then, if you need to speed things up, you have a nice, clean codebase that you can make changes to without fear that your changes will make one piece of code stomp over another piece's data.

Comment: In general, what @Chuck is saying makes sense. For another perspective, consider mobile development where memory is tight and better performance implies better battery life, etc; in iOS dev for instance, immutable `NSArray`s are used when you don't need to modify an array and its subclass, `NSMutableArray`, can be used when you need to.

Comment: @Abdo In my opinion the idea still stands in mobile development. The point is that most of your code contributes only negligibly to the CPU use of your program. Consider the 80/20 rule of thumb; if 80% of the runtime is spent in 20% of the code, then even optimizing the other 80% of the code so well that you reduced its runtime **to zero** would only win you a 20% reduction in CPU/battery consumption of your app. The time savings of writing/maintaining clean code mean that *even if performance is your goal*, you're better off only spending the time optimizing where it makes a difference.